# import Dll which build from Go and runtime error

Tags: go, dll

I have a Win64 Dll file, name "test.dll". Build it with MinGW64. Dll inside code like this:

```
// GOLANG CODE
package main

import "C"
import "time"

//export TestGo
func TestGo(str *C.char)*C.char {
    gostr := C.GoString(str)
    println("TestGo : ", str)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    gostr = "return:" + gostr
    cstr := C.CString(gostr)
    return cstr
}

func main() {

}
```

And I have another Go program , try to import this "test.dll":

```
// GOLANG CODE
package main

import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    pth := "./godll/test.dll"
    dll := syscall.NewLazyDLL(pth)
    ptrfun := dll.NewProc("TestGo")
    msg := C.CString("this is a message")
    res, _, _ := ptrfun.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(msg)))
    gostr := C.GoString((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(res)))
    fmt.Println(gostr)
    for {
        select {}
    }
}
```

When I run this program, I got this:

```
TestGo :  0x1864b921f80
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x6bf1f528]
goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw(0x6bf524d9, 0x2a)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/panic.go:1116 +0x79 fp=0xc00010ef08 sp=0xc00010eed8 pc=0x6bef2859
runtime.sigpanic()
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/signal_windows.go:240 +0x285 fp=0xc00010ef38 sp=0xc00010ef08 pc=0x6bf040a5
runtime.memmove(0x0, 0xc00004a050, 0x1)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/memmove_amd64.s:148 +0x108 fp=0xc00010ef40 sp=0xc00010ef38 pc=0x6bf1f528
runtime.heapBitsSetType(0xc00004a050, 0x50, 0x48, 0x6bf48a60)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/mbitmap.go:1373 +0x4cd fp=0xc00010f048 sp=0xc00010ef40 pc=0x6bed310d
runtime.mallocgc(0x50, 0x6bf48a60, 0x1, 0x6bf4c29e)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/malloc.go:1090 +0x5ee fp=0xc00010f0e8 sp=0xc00010f048 pc=0x6beccace
runtime.newobject(0x6bf48a60, 0x1)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/malloc.go:1195 +0x3f fp=0xc00010f118 sp=0xc00010f0e8 pc=0x6becd23f
time.Sleep(0xb2d05e00)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/time.go:182 +0x108 fp=0xc00010f158 sp=0xc00010f118 pc=0x6bf1b828
main.TestGo(0x1864b921f80, 0x0)
    C:/Users/hgmmy/Desktop/GitGoCache/maquego/Test/GoDllTest/godll/dll.go:16 +0x93 fp=0xc00010f1d0 sp=0xc00010f158 pc=0x6bf2d833
main._cgoexpwrap_0fad9edfa800_TestGo(0x1864b921f80, 0x0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:73 +0x67 fp=0xc00010f208 sp=0xc00010f1d0 pc=0x6bf2d6a7
runtime.call32(0x0, 0x55e6dff3d0, 0x55e6dff540, 0x10)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:540 +0x45 fp=0xc00010f238 sp=0xc00010f208 pc=0x6bf1cc25
runtime.cgocallbackg1(0x0)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/cgocall.go:332 +0x1b8 fp=0xc00010f2d0 sp=0xc00010f238 pc=0x6bec3558
runtime.cgocallbackg(0x0)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/cgocall.go:207 +0xe5 fp=0xc00010f338 sp=0xc00010f2d0 pc=0x6bec32e5
runtime: unexpected return pc for runtime.cgocallback_gofunc called from 0x78dca7
stack: frame={sp:0xc00010f338, fp:0xc00010f358} stack=[0xc000100000,0xc000110000)
000000c00010f238:  0000000000000000  00000055e6dff3d0 
000000c00010f248:  00000055e6dff540  0000000000000010 
000000c00010f258:  000000006befcd0f <runtime.exitsyscallfast+207>  000000c000020000 
000000c00010f268:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f278:  0202010000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f288:  0000000000000000  000000c00010f2c0 
000000c00010f298:  000000c000034000  000000c00010f27d 
000000c00010f2a8:  000000006bf539d0  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f2b8:  0000000000000000  000000c00010f328 
000000c00010f2c8:  000000006bec32e5 <runtime.cgocallbackg+229>  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f2d8:  0000000000000000  0000000000724775 
000000c00010f2e8:  000000006bf2d9a0  0000000000000001 
000000c00010f2f8:  000000c00010f3e8  000000006bf2d9a0 
000000c00010f308:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f318:  000000c00010f360  000000c000034000 
000000c00010f328:  00000055e6dff390  000000006bf1e3d2 <runtime.cgocallback_gofunc+178> 
000000c00010f338: <0000000000000000  00000000008a0020 
000000c00010f348:  000000c00010f360 !000000000078dca7 
000000c00010f358: >00000000007247a9  000000000078f880 
000000c00010f368:  00000000008a02e0  00000000008a0020 
000000c00010f378:  000000c000034000  00000000008a0020 
000000c00010f388:  000000c00010f3c8  000000000078ac1c 
000000c00010f398:  000000000078f880  00000000008a02e0 
000000c00010f3a8:  0000000000000000  0100000000000000 
000000c00010f3b8:  00000000008a0020  0000000000832f90 
000000c00010f3c8:  000000c00010fde8  000000000079e9fb 
000000c00010f3d8:  000000006bf2d9a0  0000000000000001 
000000c00010f3e8:  000001864b921f80  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f3f8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f408:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f418:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f428:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f438:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c00010f448:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
runtime.cgocallback_gofunc(0x7247a9, 0x78f880, 0x8a02e0, 0x8a0020)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:794 +0xb2 fp=0xc00010f358 sp=0xc00010f338 pc=0x6bf1e3d2

goroutine 1 [runnable, locked to thread]:
syscall.LoadDLL(0x6bf4d1ab, 0xc, 0x1c00004e078, 0x6bf6282d, 0x1c00004e000)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:92 +0x30d
syscall.(*LazyDLL).Load(0x1c000004060, 0x0, 0x0)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:245 +0xc8
syscall.(*LazyProc).Find(0x1c00004c2a0, 0x0, 0x0)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:300 +0xbf
syscall.(*LazyProc).mustFind(...)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:318
syscall.(*LazyProc).Addr(...)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:327
syscall.GetStdHandle(0xfffffffffffffff6, 0x1c00003bee8, 0x6bf280f8, 0x6bf461e0)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/syscall/zsyscall_windows.go:366 +0x3e
syscall.getStdHandle(0xfffffffffffffff6, 0x6bf4e818)
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go:467 +0x32
syscall.init()
    I:/Soft_Install/GO/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go:461 +0x129a
```

**BUT!!!**
I can call the dll with Python:
(Python Codes)

```
# PYTHON  CODE
from ctypes import *
dll=CDLL("test.dll")
dll.TestGo.restype = c_char_p
msg=create_string_buffer("this is a message".encode())
res = dll.TestGo(msg)
print(string_at(res).decode())
```

Python return this:

```
TestGo :  0x259bd3aad90
return:this is a message
```

It return correct answer.

**So, why I can't call this Dll functions from Go ......?**

Comment: Using a cgo shared library within Go imports another instance of the go runtime, which is not going to work. If you want to use the Go code from Go, import and build it normally.

Comment: @JimB What do you mean "normally"......? Actually, I have a task, make some functions to a DLL or something that Python or C or Go can import it. But Yes, I appreciate your answer. BTW,  I just thinking, what if I going to make a plugin with golang in Windows, How can I do? Plugin in Linux is grate, but not effect in Windows now.

Comment: "normally" here mean import the _Go_ package, and compile it. You cannot do what you want.

Comment: @JimB Buddy Thanks alot!  I get a big trouble from now on...sh!t PM...